# Is there a way to include grid border as part of the whole grid size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, grid

I am trying to create a layout component in react, and this layout is 1600w x 1000h.

Due to the design I have to add this thick border on the root element. However, it seems that when I add the `display=grid`, the columns start within the border and I want them to start from each edge of the page. I know I can probably play around with multiple elements, but I am trying to keep as lean as possible and was wondering if this could be achieved through CSS properties.

This is how it looks right now (12 column gutter)
[image]

As you can see each column begins right within the border, is there a way to make it overflow over the border?

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be with [outline property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#description) instead of border

Comment: can you share what you have tried to understand problem image may not be enough?